# How to copy database from SQL Server Express to SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

How to copy database and all tables pks triggers etc as well as data from SQL Server Express to SQL Server 2005 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to copy anything?? Just detach the database (MDF + LDF) from your SQL Server Express, copy the files to the full server, and re-attach the database - and you're done!

Answer (score 4):

### Using Backup/Restore

1. [Backup the database on SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) Express
2. [Restore the database to SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

### Using Detach/Attach

1. [Detach the database from SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191491%28SQL.90%29.aspx) Express
2. [Attach the database to SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191491%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

## Note

This assumes the Express Edition is 2005 as well.  Downgrading from 2008 to 2005 can be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Database Backup, or Drop the Database as Query.